# InArray returning -1 with matching value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var x = new Array(10);
$.inArray(10,x);
#Returns -1
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccFCK/)

I've come across this weird issue, checking a value in an array with `$.inArray`, really simple.

But, if the array only has one value in it, `inArray` returns `-1`. 
If I add another value to the array, it works as expected.

This only happens with integers and not with strings.

What's going on?!

Comment: You just created an array with a length of 10, not an array that contains the value 10, see the [**DOCS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Tip: 1. `console.log( x )` 2. check empty array in console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create an array with the one number(`10`) inside you should use bracket literal:

```
var x = [10];
$.inArray(10,x);
```

Or with push:

```
var x = new Array();
x.push(10);
```

Obviously the first one is more readable and faster to write.

> A JavaScript array is initialized with the given elements, **except in the case where a single argument is passed to the Array constructor and that argument is a number**. Note that this special case only applies to JavaScript arrays created with the Array constructor, not with array literals created with the bracket syntax.
>
> **If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer, a new, empty JavaScript array and its length is set to that number**
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccFCK/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check documentation for arrays in JavaScript, link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

In your case, by using:

```
var x = new Array(10);
```

It creates an array with length 10 and each item of the array is *undefined*

I suggest to use:

```
var x = [10];
```

this is an array with one item at index 0 that has value 10.

Answer (score 0):

`var x = new Array(10);` creates an array with 10 slots, not an array that contains "10"